# Laravel includes UnitTest files by default via composer autoloader in production. How to prevent?

Tags: php, unit-testing, laravel, composer-php, autoloader

By default Laravel loads all UnitTest files via the composer autoloader, the official composer.json looks like this:

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        ...      
        "app/tests/TestCase.php"
        ...
    ]
},
```

This will be used in development and in production, as there's not dev/prod switch afaik. As tests are never run in production, it might be overdozed to load them all.

**Question:**

How to prevent the Composer autoloader to load all UnitTest files in certain scenarios (like in production) ? Or am I totally misunderstanding something here ?

Comment: That just creates an autoload file so that, in this case, the TestCase class can be used in your code without you having to explicitly include or require the file "app/tests/TestCase.php."

I'm not sure exactly what you mean by "loads all UnitTest files." Your test cases only get run (is that what you mean by loaded?) when you explicitly run them.

Comment: "loads all unittest files" probably refers to them being present in the classmap and affecting memory usage and performance when parsing the classmap file, not being used when executing code.

Comment: @jboschiero Thanks, for sure the test will not be run, that's not the point. But imagine you have 1000 tests in 100 files, maybe 5MB of unused code that is loading into memory on every application request. Maybe I'm totally wrong here... but maybe not. I think we should split between autoloader in dev and in production.

Answer (score 2):

There is an option called `autoload-dev` in composer which may just be what you need. Here's the link: https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#autoload-dev

In fact, the example provided is precisely that of only autoloading Testing classes when in development mode.